# wifi drivers not appearing in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, atheros

I am unable to connect wifi in Ubuntu (version 14.04) ever since I dual-booted my Windows 8 PC, though ethernet gets connected. I have tried many methods which include calls for downloading b43.zip, bcmwl .deb files and executing commands through the terminal. Many methods even start from the assumption that the broadcom driver is visible in the 'Additional drivers' area. But no matter what I do, the driver doesn't appear in the additional drivers area. (Other answers on this topic couldn't solve my issue, hence re-asked) Thanks in advance

Additional drivers area looks like this in my PC:

[image: Additional drivers area looks like this in my PC]

The output of the command lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 is:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6164 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0041] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3545]
04:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Venus XTX [Radeon HD 8890M / R9 M275X/M375X] [1002:6820] (rev ff)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: I have added the output of the above command in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have a Broadcom wireless adapter. That is why it makes no sense to install any Broadcom drivers.

You have an Atheros adapter. It is supported in kernel 4.4. You can upgrade the kernel in Ubuntu 14.04 by running

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

You may also need to upgrade `linux-firmware` by

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware
```

Reboot after you do this. I am not 100% sure the firmware has been added to the Ubuntu package. If it is not, then you will need to install the firmware manually.

You can install the firmware manually this way:

```
echo "options ath10k_core skip_otp=Y" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf
sudo rm -r /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/
git clone https://github.com/atondwal/ath10k-firmware.git
sudo cp -r ath10k-firmware/ath10k/ /lib/firmware/
cd /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6164
sudo cp -r hw2.1/ /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/
```

[Reference](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2322547&p=13495356#post13495356)

Comment: I tried this and rebooted as well.. but the wifi drivers are probably still absent.. Just for your reference, the first install command showed some error like "err: Some archives couldn't be downloaded.... " and the second one also showed some error statements

Comment: "Some errors" can be solved by "some actions".

Comment: Exact errors will show if the kernel installed correctly. But it can be checked an easier way by running `uname -a`.

Comment: First check if the kernel is installed. If it is and the wireless does not work, install the firmware as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Pilot6.. I have got successfully connected to my wifi network now!! For the reference of other novices, the errors mentioned in my above comment occured probably because I wasn't connected to the net via ethernet. Then I connected ethernet, run the first two commands, manually installed the firmware and rebooted.. And viola, all the nearby networks popped up in the network drop-down on my  PC:D

Comment: Needless to say, don't forget to reboot after installing the firmware manually.